# Getting error while running npm-check-updates

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting below error while trying to execute below command

> **npm-check-updates**

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\hbarsainya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-check-updates\build\src\bin\cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\hbarsainya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-check-updates\build\src\bin\cli.js:11:40)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\hbarsainya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-check-updates\build\src\bin\cli.js'
  ]
  }

I see the location C:\Users\hbarsainya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-check-updates\build\src\bin\cli.js exist. Can you help me solving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround in location https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates/issues/990

I changed "../../package.json" to "../../../package.json" in /home/ledsun/.local/share/nvm/v17.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates/build/src/bin/cli.js:11, then the ncu runs expected.